# How to make content scroll not the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I would like to make a content area scroll instead of the page.

According to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/overflow/) I should be able to do this by applying a bootstrap `overflow-auto` class, but I can't get this working, for example the yellow div here;

```css
* {
  padding: 1em;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #0F0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #F00;
}

main {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.header {
  background-color: #07f;
}

.content {
  background-color: #f7f;
}

.scroll {
  background-color: #FD0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="container p-0">
    <div class="row p-0">
      <nav class="col-md-2">Nav bar</nav>
      <main class="col-md-10">
        <div class="header">
          <b>Header</b>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          <b>Title</b>
          <div class="scroll overflow-auto">
            <div class="E">1</div>
            <div class="E">2</div>
            <div class="E">3</div>
            <div class="E">4</div>
            <div class="E">5</div>
            <div class="E">6</div>
            <div class="E">7</div>
            <div class="E">8</div>
            <div class="E">9</div>
            <div class="E">10</div>
            <div class="E">11</div>
            <div class="E">12</div>
            <div class="E">10</div>
            <div class="E">11</div>
            <div class="E">12</div>
            <div class="E">10</div>
            <div class="E">11</div>
            <!--<div class="E">12</div>-->

          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Add `height` or `max-height` on `.scroll`

Comment: do you want the body height to the full window height?

Comment: @WilliamWang yep!

Comment: @LaljiTadhani can these heights be made to fill the available space?

Comment: Does my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add a scroll, you must define a height for the content (as mentioned in comments). You can define the `overflow` y axis using `overflow-y` and the `overflow` x-axis using `overflow-x`. Alternatively, you can set both axis to overflow using `overflow:auto`.

Working code:

```css
* {
  padding: 1em;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #0F0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #F00;
}

main {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.header {
  background-color: #07f;
}

.content {
  background-color: #f7f;
}

.scroll {
  background-color: #FD0;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="container p-0">
    <div class="row p-0">
      <nav class="col-md-2">Nav bar</nav>
      <main class="col-md-10">
        <div class="header">
          <b>Header</b>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          <b>Title</b>
          <div class="scroll overflow-auto">
            <div class="E">1</div>
            <div class="E">2</div>
            <div class="E">3</div>
            <div class="E">4</div>
            <div class="E">5</div>
            <div class="E">6</div>
            <div class="E">7</div>
            <div class="E">8</div>
            <div class="E">9</div>
            <div class="E">10</div>
            <div class="E">11</div>
            <div class="E">12</div>
            <div class="E">10</div>
            <div class="E">11</div>
            <div class="E">12</div>
            <div class="E">10</div>
            <div class="E">11</div>
            <!--<div class="E">12</div>-->

          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```